# What is the type of variable y in "int &y"?

Tags: c++, int

If I declare:

```
int &y;
int *x;
```

x is of type "int *", but 
What is the type of variable y? Or does it not even make sense to ask that question?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

Comment: [en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly valid question. The type of variables is an int. However both use a different way of *referencing* the variable. According to standard nomenclature, in your case x is referred to as a pointer to an int. Whereas y is a reference to an int.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I would appreciate it if there was an explanation that would go along with the downvote.